# Replacing a listview item using a template, refresh does only work partially

Tags: jquery-mobile

I replace a listview item in a jQuery mobile page based on some condition (date of the month, whatever) and I appear to be able to apply the styling only partially. The example below formats the new listview item partially correct, the link is missing its styling. What I am missing here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-beta.1.min.css"/>
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-beta.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).delegate("#index", "pageinit", function() {
        var newItem;
        if (false) {
            newItem = $("#templ1")[0].innerHTML
        } else {
            newItem = $("#templ2")[0].innerHTML
        }
        $("#item1")[0].innerHTML = newItem;
        $("#item1").parent().listview("refresh");
    });
    </script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="index">
<script id="templ1" type="text/template">
<li id="item1"><a href="#">item1 templ1</a></li>
</script>
<script id="templ2" type="text/template">
<li id="item1"><a href="#">item1 templ2</a></li>
</script>
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>test</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li data-role="list-divider">divider 1</li>
            <li id="item1"><a href="#">item1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `.replaceWith` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/RH3Su/ note that you're using beta version, jqm 1.4 isn't release yet.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using something like this (using a class insead of id so I can replace multiple items:

Comment: `function replaceItems(list, className, newItemString) {
 var lis = $.parseHTML(newItemString);
 lis = lis.slice(1, lis.length-1);
 $.each(lis, function(index, value) {
  value.className = className;
 }); 
 $("." + className).replaceWith(lis);
 list.listview("refresh");
}`